# Orientação da impressão usando JavaScript, CSS, HTML ou PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

É possível eu "pré-definir" a orientação da pagina, quando o usuário for imprimir já esteja marcado como paisagem? (Landscape)

Meu caso é o seguinte, estou com código semelhante a este exemplo

> http://programacion.net/articulo/exportar_tablas_html_a_excel_con_php_y_jquery_445

Estou exportando meu *HTML* para *Excel* e nesta parte esta tudo ok, mas o usuário não quer perder seus preciosos segundos configurando a pagina lá no Excel propriedades de impressora, ele quer ao imprimir a pagina já esteja orientada como "paisagem"(Landscape) tem como usando alguma linguagem dessas citadas ?

Comment: Não creio ser possível já configurar o `xls` para impressão em orientação `landscape`.

Comment: E se você usar a Biblioteca PHPExcel ? Vem com bastante opções de configuração, inclusive orientação de página.

Comment: @DiegoSouza eu vi essa solução, mas não queria acrescentar 228 Arquivos e 54 Pastas ao meu projeto só porque um usuário quer a pagina de ladinho....

Comment: Precisa ser Excel mesmo? Porque voce poderia fazer um botao pra download do excel que geraria o teu arquivo e outro pra exibir no navegador que usaria html mesmo, neste poderia usar CSS.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não precisa ser em excel, acabei optando por outra solução mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso a plataforma do servidor seja Windows. O que você pode fazer é criar um macro em VBS para fazer isso. Crie o arquivo: **worksheet.vbs**

```
$file = 'seu_arquivo.xls';
$path = "C:\\temp\\";
$fp = fopen($path.'worksheet.vbs', 'w');

$content = '
 Sub setUpPage(sheet) 
       With Workbooks("'.$file.'")
          .Sheets (sheet).PageSetup
          .Orientation = xlLandscape 
          .PaperSize = xlPaperA4 
          .Zoom = False
          .FitToPagesWide = 1 
          .FitToPagesTall = False 
       End With 
     End Sub 
';

fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

Ou sem passar arquivo, criar sem escrever:

```
Sub Macro()
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
    End With
End Sub
```

E no PHP, execute-o:

```
if (file_exists("{$path}worksheet.vbs")) {
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
    $obj = $WshShell->Run("cscript {$path}worksheet.vbs", 0, true); 
}
```

[**Aqui**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.com.php) tem mais informações.

Comment: Vou testar assim que possível lhe retorno

Comment: Amigo parece um boa resposta, mas `new COM` roda do lado do servidor e ainda o servidor tem que ser Windows pra poder usar `new COM`, o AP parece que necessita que isto ocorra do lado do cliente. Ate mais :)

Comment: @SneepSNinjA voce quer imprimir em um impressora no servidor? Ou voce quer imprimir do lado do cliente?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, concordo com você, porém é possível criar uma VM no servidor Linux para esse tipo de execução, se for necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei usando a solução do [JasperServer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86040/jasperserver-com-php) com PHP tem uma [integração no git](https://github.com/adlermedrado/PHP-JasperServer-Integration) que faz essa conexão é bem simples

um trecho de exemplo:

```
try {
    $jasper = new Adl\Integration\RequestJasper();
    /*
    To send output to browser
    */
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    echo $jasper->run('/reports/samples/AllAccounts');

    /*
    To Save content to a file in the disk
    The path where the file will be saved is registered into config/data.ini
    */
    //$jasper->run('/reports/samples/AllAccounts','PDF', null, true);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz no CSS uma vez e um Plugin JS chamado **printElement.js**, porém não é necessário se for uma página simples.

[Print Element](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)

### CSS

```
@media print{

    @page{
        size: landscape;
    }

    #image-example{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

}
```

Daí na página que vai ser imprimida só chamar o arquivo CSS com:

`media='print'`

Comment: Não creio que vá resolver o problema, já que ele está "exportando para excel", ou seja, resolveria se ele estivesse imprimindo a página HTML.

Comment: pior que testei e não resolveu... nem com o plugin