# jasperserver com php

Tags: php, soap, jasper-reports, ireport

Achei uma lib no Git https://github.com/adlermedrado/PHP-JasperServer-Integration que permite que o PHP se conecte com o JasperServer ( servidor ireport do java ), eu já uso e funciona, mas eu queria adicionar uma funcionalidade a este projeto, atualmente ele só aceita um array de parametros conforme abaixo:

```
    private function _requestMock($report, $format, $params)
    {

        if (is_array($params)) {
            $reportParams = "";
            foreach ($params as $name => $value) {
                $reportParams .= "<parameter name=\"$name\"><![CDATA[$value]]></parameter>\n";
            }
        } else {
            $reportParams = '';
        }

        $xmlTemplate = <<<XML_TEMPLATE
        <request operationName="runReport" locale="pt_BR">
            <argument name="RUN_OUTPUT_FORMAT">{$format}</argument>
            <resourceDescriptor name="" wsType="" uriString="{$report}" isNew="false">
                <label>null</label>
                {$reportParams}
            </resourceDescriptor>
        </request>
XML_TEMPLATE;
        return $xmlTemplate;
    }
```

O que eu queria é fazer é passar um array de objetos, mas não sei como ficaria o o arquivo do ireport para receber um tipo Array de Objetos lá, não sei nem se isso é possível

Comment: Você quer passar um array de objetos para usar como parâmetro na consulta sql?

Comment: isso mesmo, na verdade nem preciso fazer a consulta sql, com esses objetos eu já iria preencher o formulário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução: abandonar a lib do Adler e utilizar diretamente requisições Rest para o Jasperserver.

1) Fazer o download do módulo PHP versão 2 (procurar no site do JasperServer, http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/php-client-getting-started)

2) Fazer includes de todos os arquivos php do módulo (não consegui fazer a inclusão direta pelo phar e composer como recomendado na documentação, então fiz include dos arquivos um a um)

3) acrescentar no seu código

```
use Jaspersoft\Client\Client;
use Jaspersoft\Exception\RESTRequestException;

 $jasperclient = new Jaspersoft\Client\Client(
                "http://192.168.56.102:8080/jasperserver",
                "jasperadmin",
                "jasperadmin"
            );

//aqui vai o array de controles e valores conforme o relatório que quer executar
 $controls = array('p_data' => '2017-06-20');

//aqui executa o relatório registrado no jasperserver, passando o array acima
$report = $jasperclient->reportService()->runReport('/reports/teste_telemkt', 'pdf', null, null, $controls);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $report;
```

Comment: valeu Luiz Soares, já me resolve o problema !